# neo4j 3.0.3 pathexpanderbuilder's addNodeFilter method clarification

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using PathExpanderBuilder api to find the shortestpath between two nodes.

When I am implementing addNodeFilter method of PathExpanderBuilder clas , It is using ALL/NONE predicate internally BY DEFAULT for all nodes of a perticular path  .

Because of this , no path is matching and it is giving no paths.

Is there any way that traversal happens with ANY predicate.So that if one of the nodes matches the conditions, it will return the corresponding path.

I want to use java api only instead of cypher.

Can somebody give the significance of addNodeFilter method of PathExpanderBuilder class .If you can give me the github link, it will be helful .

Comment: Did you eventually come to solve this? I'm facing the same issue, `addNodeFilter` doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: No, Observed that addNodeFilter applying filter to all nodes of specific path and filter should be satisfied by all nodes,it is using ALL predicate internally. You use cypher instead